# How do I grep some blocks of text

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to extract somne blocks from a text, however, it does not work now.

For example: I have a file named test01.txt with below contents:

```
10:10:12 ::  blah blah blah
10:10:12 ::  blah blah blah
10:10:14 ::  $VAR1 = {
10:10:14 ::     'Id' = 'A0002'
10:10:15 ::     'Name' => 'Jane'
10:10:15 ::     'Age' => '18'
10:10:15 ::  };
10:10:15 ::  blah blah blah
10:10:16 ::  blah blah blah
10:10:16 ::  $VAR1 = {
10:10:16 ::     'Id' = 'A0003'
10:10:16 ::     'Name' => 'Adams'
10:10:16 ::     'Age' => '25'
10:10:16 ::  };
```

expect results

```
{
    10:10:14 ::     'Id' = 'A0002'
    10:10:15 ::     'Name' => 'Jane'
    10:10:15 ::     'Age' => '18'
    10:10:15 ::  }
 {
    10:10:16 ::     'Id' = 'A0003'
    10:10:16 ::     'Name' => 'Adams'
    10:10:16 ::     'Age' => '25'
    10:10:16 ::  }
```

I have used the following command "`grep -e '{|}' test01.txt`", which does not solve this problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the criteria for the lines that should be returned?

Comment: @Barmar  only the strings inside { ....}  can be saved.

Comment: `grep` operates on one line at a time. You can't tell it to match lines between other lines.

Comment: Use `sed` or `awk` for this.

Comment: @Barmar  we can use prep, a similar task see:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232509/how-do-i-find-block-of-text-from-a-text-file-containing-a-specific-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `grep` because it just matches single lines, not groups of lines.

Use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/p' test01.txt
```

This prints the line ranges starting from a line that matches `{` and ending with a line that matches `}`.
[

Comment: thanks for your support, it can be solved by using grep see the answer "JdeHaan" from the post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232509/how-do-i-find-block-of-text-from-a-text-file-containing-a-specific-string?noredirect=1&lq=1